# How do I access Combobox item MemberValue in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to access a combobox item's value. The item's value is of type MyClass

```
List<MyClass> myIitemsList = getMyClassItemsMethod();
if (myIitemsList .Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myIitemsList .Count; i++)
    {         
        List<MyClass> selectedMyClassItems = myIitemsList .FindAll(x => x.myClassNumber == i);
        string itemtext = "MyClass " + i ;
        myComboBox.Items.Add(new { itemtext, ValueMember = selectedMyClassItems});
    }
}
```

here is my sample code. Now i am trying to access the ValueMember. When I select an item in the combobox, I am able to get the selected item.

```
var ddlMyClassSelectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

In the Debug Watch windo, I am able to see that the ValueMember for the item has the items as a list, but I don't know how to access/retrieve them.

Comment: Your codes doesn't compile. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Make your class override the ToString() method and return whatever you need to describe an instance of MyClass then set the DataSource of the combo to the List<MyClass> and set the ValueMember property of the combo to the identifying member of MyClass

Comment: I am not using a datasource, I am manually adding items trhough the for loop as shown in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets discuss what you've done. How you retrieve your members is of little interest, although you could do it this way

```
myComboBox.DisplayMemeber = "Display";
myComboBox.ValueMemeber = "Value";
myComboBox.DataSource = 
    getMyClassItemsMethod().OrderBy(c => c.myClassNumber).
    Select(c => new { Display = "Memeber: " + c.myClassNumber, Value = c}).ToList();
```

It will work and now you have selected an item using `myComboBox.SelectedItem`. But you running into a problem that your item is in fact an anonymous type and you can't cast it easily.

On this note, why don't you declare a type like

```
class ComboItem
{
    public string Display {get; set;}        
    public MyClass Value {get; set;}
}
```

And use this type instead of anonymous type. i.e. instead of `new {...}` you do `new ComboItem {...}`. Now, this is easy

```
var ddlMyClassSelectedItem = (ComboItem)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
Console.WriteLine(ddlMyClassSelectedItem.Value.myClassNumber);
```

Now you know that `ddlMyClassSelectedItem` is of `ComboItem` type

Comment: using the ComboItem class suggesstion worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When adding to the combobox, use:

```
myComboBox.Items.Add(selectedMyClassItems);
```

When retrieving the item, use:

```
List<MyClass> ddlMyClassSelectedItem = myComboBox.SelectedItem as List<MyClass>;
```

And finally, in MyClass, override ToString (so combobox can render it as you like):

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "MyClass " + myClassNumber;
    }
```

Comment: I figured out a solution that works, but it is not clean. I am adding the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyClass> myIitemsList = getMyClassItemsMethod();
if (myIitemsList .Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myIitemsList .Count; i++)
    {         
        List<MyClass> selectedMyClassItems = myIitemsList .FindAll(x => x.myClassNumber == i);
        string itemtext = "MyClass " + i ;
        myComboBox.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<SwitchPort>>(itemtext,
                            selectedMyClassItems);
    }
}
```

then to retrieve the value from the selected item.

```
var item = myComboBox.SelectedItem;
KeyValuePair<string,List<MyClass>> selectedItemsPair = (KeyValuePair<string,List<MyClass>>)item;
List<MyClass> myClassList = selectedItemsPair.Value;
```

The only issue with this, is that the items in my combox show as:

```
My class 1, [System.Collection]
My Class 2, [System.Collection]
My Class 3, [System.Collection]
My Class 4, [System.Collection]
My Class 5, [System.Collection]
```